# Calculating multiple datetimes for total hours

Tags: jquery, mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Working on a rails 5.0.0 app which has a simple timecard module, I am trying to figure out how to compare all the datetimes in the "time" field and get total of hours worked...

Solution can be either in ruby, mysql or jquery, since I am using all three in the application.

DB fields are: user, clock, time

HTML: date and time located in the "ts-time" div

```
<div class="ts-time"></div>
```

Have provided a couple of screenshots below

Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

Comment: No screenshots thanks. Just provide proper  CREATE and INSERT statements AND a desired result

Comment: Do I need to add two different datetime fields "clock_in" and "clock_out" or is having one "time" datetime field enough for hour calculations?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways that you can store timesheet information, two of them are:

#### Series of events

(Looks like this is what you do, according to the screenshot)

Store a point in time, store the type of the event (in, out, lunch, break).
The types seem to be just variations of **start** and **stop** of work.
A **stop** always needs a preceding **start** (can't stop unless you started) and a **start** always needs a **stop** event in order to be able to calculate the total hours worked (which is then the sum of all the differences between consecutive **start** and **stop** events)

```
13:00 in (start)
14:00 break (stop)
14:15 in (start)
14:45 out (stop)

=> 1.5 hours
```

#### Series of durations

You store either of

- **start**/**stop**
- **start**/**duration**
- **duration** (if you do not care when in the day the work happened)

I'd prefer the "duration" style, easier to calculate, less error prone (what happens if you don't clock out?)